# Rails 4.1 - Thinking-Sphinx Search with many-to-many through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm making an app with three model objects, `Team`, `Users` and `Member`, `Member` is a join table between `Team` and `Users`. So each `Team` can have many members, and each `User` can be a member of multiple teams.

The relationship looks like this:

```
# Team.rb
has_many :members
has_many :users, through: :members

# User.rb
has_many :members
has_many :teams, through: :members
```

What I want to do is to search for members that are in a specific team. Currently I get `no` results.

My indexes looks like this:

```
# user_index
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :real_time do
  indexes name
  indexes email
  indexes about

  has team_id, type: :integer
  has created_at, type: :timestamp
  has updated_at, type: :timestamp

  indexes members.team.name, :as => :teams
end

# team_index
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :team, :with => :real_time do
  indexes name

  has created_at, type: :timestamp
  has updated_at, type: :timestamp

  indexes members.user.name, :as => :members

end

# member_index.rb
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :member, :with => :real_time do

  has user_id, type: :integer
  has team_id, type: :integer
  has created_at, type: :timestamp
  has updated_at, type: :timestamp

end
```

My `members_controller` index action (where I perform the search) - looks like this:

```
def index

  @team = Team.find_by_id(params[:team_id])
  @users = @team.users.search(params[:search], :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

end
```

I have checked that the team actually has users, but @users always returns 0. Any ideas on how I should do to make it work as I want?

**Update**

I use Rails: 4.1.4
And thinking-sphink: 3.1.1

My Sphinx query looks like this:

```
Sphinx Query (0.7ms)  SELECT * FROM `member_core` WHERE MATCH('Anders') AND `team_id` = 2 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 10
```

Sphinx  Found 0 results

With slightly updated controller code:

```
@members = @team.members.search(params[:search], :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Comment: Can you look at the Rails logs and spot the corresponding SphinxQL query that's being made?

Comment: Also: which versions of Rails and Thinking Sphinx are you using?

Comment: @pat I have updated my question, and hopefully answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks for that - is the team id correct in that query? And what if you try the following: `Member.search 'Anders', :with => {:team_id => @team.id}`

Comment: @pat thanks, using: `Member.search params[:search], :with => {:team_id => @team.id}` results with the same behaviour as I had before. Note: empty search params returns all users, but when I have a search params (e.g. 'Anders') I currently get 0 results.

Comment: According to your index definitions above, there's no fields in the index for Member - so that actually sounds like the expected behaviour (there's no fields to match the query 'Anders' against).

Comment: Thanks, adding indexed to `Member` seemed to help. However, I'm no experiencing another error. If I try to search for an email address, like anders@gmail.com, I get the following error: `index member_core: query error: no field 'gmail' found in schema`, do you know what causes this, and what I can do to fix it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the original cause of this issue was that there was a search query being provided, but no fields to match against. Adding fields fixed that, which is great.

The second issue, noted in the comments above, is that when you search for an email address, a query error is raised. This is because the @ character signifies a field name in the query (to limit searches to a specific field - for example `"@name Anders"` to search for Anders within a field called name).

You have two ways around this... either you escape the query by wrapping it in `ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(params[:query])`, or if you're searching for a specific email address, then I would suggest using ActiveRecord instead (given you're almost certainly going to have a unique constraint on email addresses in your database, hence there should only be zero or one matching records). The latter approach also means there's no need to have email as an indexed field, which is a bit more secure if you're letting anyone define your search queries via parameters. Letting someone search for 'gmail' and they get back all your users with gmail addresses is probably not a wise idea.

Comment: Thanks, where should I place `ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(params[:query])` if I would use that? If I add this to my controller: `@members = Member.search ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(params[:search]), :with => {:team_id => @team.id}`, then I get the following error: `undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass.`

Comment: Solved the comment above by adding an if statement to check if the search params is present. Thanks @pat!